# How can I merge visible layers into a new layer?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I used `activeDocument.mergeVisibleLayers();`, but that's not what I want, because it excludes other layers. In Photoshop shortcuts, I used to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should've been a boolean to tell PS if you want to flatten the layers or not, but as it often a case with DOM code, there's none. AM code for rescue!

```
var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
desc.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('Dplc'), true); // true to merge to new, false to flatten
executeAction(charIDToTypeID('MrgV'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
```